# I can't find component made in construction script

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

[Construction code]
RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject(TEXT("RootComponent"));
MeshComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject(TEXT("MeshComponent"));
MeshComponent->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());

```
Camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera Component"));
Camera->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());
Camera->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(-300.f, 0.f, 300.f));
Camera->SetRelativeRotation(FRotator(-45.f, 0.f, 0.f));
```

[Header File]
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
class UStaticMeshComponent* MeshComponent;

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
class UCameraComponent* Camera;
```

[Result]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HmPk.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way to have components show in the editor the way you expect them to is to define them as such:

```
private:
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class UCameraComponent* Camera;
```